# Display dynamic text instead of 3D object in vuforia android sample after image recognition?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality, vuforia-cloud-recognition

What I want to do is display text instead of 3D object in vuforia sample after image recognition. Like if I scan a shoe image, it should display the name of the shoe, brand and shoe details in real time.

I have browsed a lot but haven't been able to find solution to it.A code sample to do it would really help.

Answer (score 0):

What u could do is Create a Image and download [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/unity-samples-ui-25468) asset from asset store . Select the image and in Inspector menu , Select source of the asset u downloaded according to your needs . After this create a text from ui and make it child of Image . 
And in defaulttrackableevent create a new class with name of image

```
public Transform image;
```

and in tracking found

```
image.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

and in tracking lost

```
 image.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

---

and after writing the code , just link the image to the defaulttrackableeventhandler script.